# Compiling 2 top level directories containing sub-directories and java files into a java jar file UNIX

Tags: java, class, unix, jar, javac

I am looking to generate a jar file to run with a simple java file.
I have 2 directioes, one of whihc contains multiple sub-driectories, and under that, more sub directories. The files in the folders are all .java files. I have tried multiple approaches to this - and have created a jar file which does work.

I think my problem may be that when I create a jar file using:

```
    jar cvf newJarFile.jar -C src/ .
```

Im working with java files when they should be class files therefore it wont compile with my java file.

When i run the following to generate class files, i get a load of errors:

eg. $ find -name "*.java" > sources.txt
    $ javac @sources.txt

```
                                                         ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors
3 warnings
```

Comment: You only show two warnings which include instructions how you can get more details. 
Show the real errors if you need help to fix them. 
Does the directory structure correspond to the package structure in the `.java` files?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: what doe you mean by this - Does the directory structure correspond to the package structure in the .java files? I think it does, when i open up the java files, the imports take the correct structure, although should they have the full path name?

Comment: Please show the **full error message in your question**. With "directory structure matching the packages" I mean if `File.java` file contains `package foo.bar;` it should be located in `foo/bar/File.java`.